# Is This Implementation of AnonymousThread Correct?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe5

The  MCVE describing the idea is the following. There is an array of classes/records that have a method that takes an input parameter and calculates some result that is stored in one of its variables:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    FLastResult: double;
    procedure DoHeavyMath(Input: double);
  end;
var
  MyRecordArray:array [0..999] of TMyRecord;
  InputData:array [0..999] of double;
implementation

procedure TMyRecord.DoHeavyMath(Input: double);
begin
  FLastResult:=Input;//Here should be some math
end;
```

I am creating anonymous threads and limit the number of processes (threads) working simultaneously.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ThreadsCounter, i: word;
begin
  ThreadsCounter := 0;

  for i := 0 to 999 do
  begin
    while ThreadsCounter >= 4 { or other limit } do
    begin
    end;

    inc(ThreadsCounter);
    TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure
      begin
        MyRecordArray[i].DoHeavyMath(InputData[i]);
        dec(ThreadsCounter)
      end).Start;
  end;
  repeat
  until ThreadsCounter = 0;
  // return to main thread tasks
end;
```

Is this threads' implementation correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because assuming that you tested your code, and you think it is "correct"; then you are actually asking for a code review; and that should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not correct. There is a data race on `ThreadsCounter`. Use an atomic function instead, for instance `AtomicDecrement`.

The performance won't be very good because you incur significant overhead when creating a thread. Use a thread pool instead so that threads can be re-used. The busy loops aren't going to help performance one bit.

Comment: I've undeleted the Q. SO encourages deleting bad Qs. I can remind you that there are even bages for deleting own Qs having low rating.

Comment: Changing the `inc` and `dec` to `Atomic[Increment|Decrement]` causes External exception C000001D.

Comment: Doesn't sound right. Thanks should work. Works for me just fine. Perhaps there's an issue with variable capture in your delphi compiler. Is InterlockedIncrement any better.

Comment: `Interlocked[Increment|Decrement]` do not cause exception but deadly hang at `repeat until` section. It seems that the `ThreadsCounter` must be compared to 0 atomicaly

Comment: No, there's no problem with that. Unless of course your variable is not aligned. I wonder if it is after capture.

Comment: It was my fault. I changed the code at the begining of proceudre and the conter was set to 1. We must just use `InterlockedIncrement`.

Comment: The whole idea to create threads in circle seems to be pernicious. However I have no idea of how to cath the end of calculation of result in each of the pre-created threads without a circle and `WaitFor`. I guess that messages dispatchig is even worse.

Comment: When an anonymous thread is ending, make a synchroniced call to an event handler. If thread count is zero, you know that all work is done. That will avoid busy loops.

Comment: @LURD Actually it sounds the same as dispatching messages to the Form. OK. For instance the pre-created threads # 1, 2, 3, 4  are started within the for `i:=0 to 999 do` loop. How can we know within this loop that one of the threads (ex. #2) has finished calculations and we can load a new i-th value into it? I see only one way - to create an inner loop and check some flags in the threads. Or the other idea. There should be a secondary TThread starting the tertialy calculating threads and cheking their status in a loop.

Comment: If you mean to use a thread pool, control the loading from a thread. Use semaphores to signal when a thread is ready for a new job.